# CSS styles not being applied to dynamic HTML (ASP.NET MVC3)

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, slickgrid

I have some HTML being generated in the controller and passed to the view to be added to a "SlickGrid". The problem I'm having, is that the CSS styles that SHOULD be applied are not being applied to that HTML. It's happening in a couple of instances, all with the same symptoms.

The HTML that is displayed is this (taken from Chrome's inspector tool):

```
 <div id="pba-progress-688-5" class="checkpointLegend clickable A tipper" title="Approved&lt;br&gt;&lt;i&gt;Composition Table&lt;/i&gt;&lt;br&gt;Click to go to this checkpoint.">✓</div>
```

The classes clickable, A, Tipper are not being applied, AND there is some checkpointLegend stuff that is not being applied as well.

checkPointLegend looks like this:

```
.checkpointLegend {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.checkpointLegend div {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    float: left;
    height: 14px;
    margin: 2px;
    width: 12px;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The .checkpointLegend portion *IS* being applied, but the DIV part is NOT being applied.

Any thoughts as to why these classes are not being applied to the HTML when it is rendered?

For reference:

- I'm using a fork of SlickGrid (https://github.com/andrewchilds/SlickGrid)
- The CSS works fine in a WEBGRID (so I know it works), but the webgrid is too slow to handle the amount of data I'm throwing at it.
- The controller generates the HTML and passes it to the view via an ajax call. The html is dumped directly into a cell in the slickgrid.

I'd be happy to clarify anything that needs to be clarified, or post more code if needed.

Any thoughts/pointers/suggestions/solutions would be GREATLY appreciated (I've been banging my head off my desk for 2 days on this...)

Comment: Look at your HTML - there is NO DIV inside your checkpointLegend element.

Comment: It's amazing what happens when someone else looks at your code and sees something stupid that you've done. I guess I was supposed to wrap each group of those lines in a <div> block. @Diodeus If you want to throw your comment in as an answer, I'll mark is as correct so you get credit! Thanks for being a second pair of eyes!

Comment: No worries. Sometimes you just need a fresh set of eyeballs.